# A proof of theorem in functional analysis

Tags: functional-analysis

So, the theorem states the following:

Let $f:(a,b)\to \Bbb R$ be a function. Then $f$ is convex if and only if it holds:

$(1)\quad(\forall x,y,z) (a<x<y<z<b),\left|
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
x & y & z \\
f(x) & f(y) & f(z) \end{array}
\right|\geq 0$

which is furthermore equivalent to

$(2)\quad\dfrac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} \leq\dfrac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x} \leq \dfrac{f(z)-f(y)}{z-y}.$

I do see how convexity is equivalent to $(1)$ but I don't see how $(1)$ is equivalent to $(2)$. Help!!

Comment: You can subtract column 1 of the matrix from columns 2 and 3 and evaluate the determinant. Then you can subtract column 3 from 2 and 1 and evaluate the determinant. This will help you show that (1) implies (2).  For the converse implication, you can use proof by contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f$ is convex.Then, for all $x<y<z$ write
$$y=x+\frac{y-x}{z-x}(z-x) = x + \lambda (z-x)$$
note that $0<\lambda<1$, so
$$f(y) = f(x + \lambda(z-x)) \leq f(x) + \lambda (f(z)-f(x))$$
manipulating this you get $$\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} \leq \frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}$$
which shows your first inequality. As for the second, note that
$$\frac{f(y)-f(z)+f(z)-f(x)}{y-x} \leq \frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}$$ implies
$$\frac{f(y)-f(z)}{y-x} \leq (f(z)-f(x))\left(\frac{1}{z-x} - \frac{1}{y-x}\right) = \frac{(f(z)-f(x))(y-z)}{(z-x)(y-x)}$$
so you can get the second inequality
$$\frac{f(y)-f(z)}{y-z} \geq \frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}$$

Viceversa, for all $x<z$, for all $0<\lambda<1$ you have $x<x+\lambda(z-x)<z$, so
$$\frac{f(x+\lambda(z-x))-f(x)}{x+\lambda(z-x)-x} \leq \frac{f(z)-f(x)}{z-x}$$
and multiplying by $\lambda(z-x)$ you get
$$f(x+\lambda(z-x)) \leq f(x) +\lambda (f(z)-f(x))$$
and so $f$ is convex.